# Is command-line upgrade broken on CiviCRM 4.7.7?

Tags: upgrade, drush, cli

I just tried upgrading a very vanilla site from 4.7.6 to 4.7.7.  I ran `drush civicrm-upgrade-db`, which has worked previously on this site (which receives every point update - it's our internal CRM that serves as a testbed).

I received the following error:

```
WD php:                                                              [error]
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
You have requested a non-existent service "sql_triggers". in
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (line 317 of
/path/to/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "sql_triggers". in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (line 317 of /path/to/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
```

Upgrading via the web URL worked fine.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I've only done one site to 4.7.7 so far but drush worked without a hiccup in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone actually provided the answer to another person on the [CiviCRM chat channel](https://chat.civicrm.org), so I'm posting it here:

```
<juri_> "You have requested a non-existent service 'sql_triggers'."
<juri_> anyone care to take a guess? this is civi on drupal 8.
<mollux> juri_ clear the CiviCRM cache, had the same issue yesterday
```

Comment: I just hit this error too, but happens from both drush and the UI, and clearing cache didn't help. Anyone have insight into how the service builder works?

Comment: Good to remember that `drush cc all` does not seem to include `drush cc civicrm`.

Comment: @artfulrobot That didn't sound right so I checked and it seems [drush cc all includes drush cc civicrm](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/blob/7.x-master/drush/civicrm.drush.inc#L769-L773).

Comment: Hmmm, that's odd, I've had trouble with this many times. Just the other day I had done cc all and things were still broken but a dedicated cc civicrm fixed it. Well I'll keep the comment there, accepting it's untrue, because for whatever reason sometimes it does seem more effective when called in its own.